# How to fix WHILE directive when using GCC?

Tags: gcc, arm

In my former workplace, we used to develop a lot of our ARM v7 assembly codes with Keil muvision IDE. It became very common for me to abuse the WHILE directive for parametrisable duplication of code lines (see example, which works in Keil IDE).

I now want to port some of these codes to make them run on my raspberry pi. I managed to solve every issues that I could face when leaving the ease that keil IDE can provide but I am struggling with this last part. GCC won't recognise any of the WHILE directive instruction (WHILE, WEND,GBLA,etc). Any idea how to work around that problem or is there any equivalent to WHILE directives that would not affect the timings nor the code size?

I compile by invoking the following command:
gcc main.c *.h *.S -o exe

```
    GBLA        var
var SETA     0
    WHILE var < DEFINED_VALUE
    LDR     R4, [R7, #var*4]
    EOR     R4, R4, R5, LSL #16
    STR     R4, [R0, #var*4]
var SETA var+1
    WEND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the directives `.set`, `.rept`/`.endr` and `.set` to achieve what you want.

Example:

```
.set var, 0
.rept 5
    LDR  R4, [R7, #var*4]
    EOR  R4, R4, R5, LSL #16
    STR  R4, [R0, #var*4]
.set var,var+1
.endr
```

The result is as follows:

```
$ gcc test.s -o test.o -c
$ objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e5974000        ldr     r4, [r7]
   4:   e0244805        eor     r4, r4, r5, lsl #16
   8:   e5804000        str     r4, [r0]
   c:   e5974004        ldr     r4, [r7, #4]
  10:   e0244805        eor     r4, r4, r5, lsl #16
  14:   e5804004        str     r4, [r0, #4]
  18:   e5974008        ldr     r4, [r7, #8]
  1c:   e0244805        eor     r4, r4, r5, lsl #16
  20:   e5804008        str     r4, [r0, #8]
  24:   e597400c        ldr     r4, [r7, #12]
  28:   e0244805        eor     r4, r4, r5, lsl #16
  2c:   e580400c        str     r4, [r0, #12]
  30:   e5974010        ldr     r4, [r7, #16]
  34:   e0244805        eor     r4, r4, r5, lsl #16
  38:   e5804010        str     r4, [r0, #16]
```

See also: [Useful assembler directives and macros for the GNU assembler](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/useful-assembler-directives-and-macros-for-the-gnu-assembler).